# RabbitMQ channel has no consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I am trying to send a message to RabbitMQ via MQTT, however when the connection is established, the channel shows that is has `... no consumers ...`. To my understanding, upon connecting via MQTT to RabbitMQ, the topic will default to the `amq.topic`, and a new queue will be created for these connections.
Oddly enough, this does happen when I connect using Mosquitto, however, other MQTT clients do not get their own queue.

So, as an example, connecting like so: `mosquitto_sub -h rabbit-01.<hostname.com> -p 1883 -u <v_host>:<username> -P <pass> -t "#"`
produces:
[image]

HOWEVER!
my connection from the other server pub/sub mqtt integration thing results in no new queue displaying. Here are the settings for that:
[image]

Any help would be greatly apprecieated!

Thanks!